Circular Dependency between two schemas in NestJS
I have created two resources: Organisation and User. Each Organisation contains a certain number of users. Following the Principle of Least Cardinality, I keep the organisationId as a foreign key inside my user schema and not vice-versa. Now to keep queries of the form return the list of users belonging to the organisation with a given id efficient, I add a virtual users field in my Organisation Schema.
More on this can be found here:
So my code looks something like this:
OrganisationSchema.virtual("users", {
    ref:_User.name,               // The model to use
    localField: "_id",            // Field in the organisation schema
    foreignField: "organisationId", // Field in the _User schema
});

in the organisation schema, and
export class _User {
    
    @Prop({ required: true })
    id: string 
    @Prop()
    name: string
    @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
    email: string
    @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
    username: string
    @Prop({ required: true, type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:_Organisation.name })
    organisationId: Types.ObjectId
}

But this creates a circular dependency in NestJs, since Organisation depends on User and User depends on Organisation.
I cant simply use the name of the collections instead of _Organisation.name and _User.name, because I get an error stating the schema hasn't been registered. I also tried using forwardRef and lazy loading of modules, but none of them works.
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?
